# Splitting filenames to find files that I want to interrogate

Tags: python

I have a folder structure as follows:

```
TestOpt > roll_1_oe_2017-03-10
        > roll_2_oe_2017-03-05
           :           :
        > roll_600_oe_2012-05-10
```

TestOpt is the main folder and roll*__oe_* are the sub folders which hold .csv records that I am looking to interrogate if they are inside a certain range of rolls.

I am trying to analyse the file names as I only wish to interrogate records where he sub folder has a roll greater than say 500 (so I would like to interrogate the records in folder `roll_500_oe_2012-05-10` to `roll_600_oe_2012-05-10` inclusive)

I have tried splitting the folder name by `"_"` so I can retrieve the roll number, but I am having a problem in that I can't get the code past the TestOpt filename.  Please see below for code:

```
rootdir = r'C:/Users/Stacey/Documents/TestOpt/'

     #cycle through all the folders in the TestOpt directory
     for dirName,sundirList, fileList in os.walk(rootdir):
         #print('Found directory: %s' % dirName)
         #split the file name by _ 
         x = dirName.split("_")
         print('list length ',len(x))
         #If the length of the folder name is greater than 1 its not the TestOpt folder
         if len(x) > 1:
             #the second split list element is the roll number
             roll = x[2]
             #interrogate records in folder id roll is greater or equal to 500
             if roll >= 500:
                 print('myroll1 ',roll)
                 for fname in fileList:
                     do something....
```

If anyone can offer any assistance I would be most grateful

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to explicitly state that `roll` is an integer, as the list made from the filename is a list of strings.

Use `roll = int(x[2])`.